# How do you find the first element in array that has a certain characteristic?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

For example if you are searching through an array that deals with parts and you are trying to find the first element in that array that has a certain weight. Like if the weight was 10 and in the parts array the first element(part) had a weight of 15 and the second element(part) had a weight of 10 it would return that element. These are the methods that I used.I need to make another method though and I think I might need to call one of these.

```
class Robot {
Part[] parts;
    public Robot () { // implementation is not shown }
    public void addPart(PArt p) { // implementation not shown }
}

class Part {
// Class details not shown
    public double getWeight() {
    }
    public int get Partnum() {

    }
    public getMaterial() {

    }
}
```

Comment: your question makes no understanding... please read it again and try to understand... if you get explain us too...

Comment: Further to @FahimParkar's comment - what have you tried and where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
double searchForLen = 10.00;
for (int i=0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  if (parts[i].getWeight() == searchForLen) {
    return parts[i];
  }
}
```

I would take Brian's advice and change the **type** of the weight. If you insist on staying with **double** you can use **Double** and then call Double.compare()

Comment: Ignoring the fact that your syntax is wrong, comparing `double` values like that is problematic at best. He should be using `BigDecimal` or ounces/grams represented as an `int`

Comment: @FahimParkar my code returns the first part found - as requested. Brian - what's wrong with the syntax ?

Comment: @alfasin - `parts.[i].getWeight()` ; that won't even compile. It's `parts[i].getWeight()`

Comment: Also ... and I'm really not trying to harp here, `Double.compare()` has the same problem as using `==`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/393383/302916 . An ugly but informative page explaining in detail can be found here: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @BrianRoach you got a point but I think that this is a bit "overkill" since measuring weight will probably produce a number in the format of xx.xx (which can easily be compared using a double data type) so all this discussion is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

First off ... you can't use a `double` and expect things to compare as you expect. Floating point numbers are not precise. You should use `BigDecimal` or change to using the lowest commmon denominator (e.g. ounces or grams) represented as an `int` for your weight.

After that ... iterate through the array until you find a match for the weight you're looking for. It's that simple.

```
public Part findFirst(int weight)
{
    // This will allow us to return null if there's no match
    Part p = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
    {
        // after changing getWeight() to return an int
        if (parts[i].getWeight() == weight)
        {
            p = parts[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    return p;
}
```