# how do you find the first element in array that has a certain detail?

Tags: java, eclipse

For example if you are searching through an array that deals with parts and you are trying to find the first element in that array that has a certain weight. Like if the weight was 10 and in the parts array the first element(part) had a weight of 15 and the second element(part) had a weight of 10 it would return that element. These are the methods that I used.I need to make another method though and I think I might need to call one of these.

```
class Robot {
Part[] parts;
    public Robot () {// assume these are right}
    public void addPart(Part p) { // assume these are right}
}

class Part {
// Class details not shown
    public double getWeight() {//... }
    public int get Partnum() {//...}
    public getMaterial() {//...}
}
```

Comment: why are you posting the same question again ? this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246725/how-do-you-find-the-first-element-in-array-that-has-a-certain-characteristic/9246800#9246800

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the array and return when the part weight is found. Rough code for example:

```
public Part getPart(Double requiredWeight){
for(int i=0;i<parts.length();i++){
if(parts[i].getWeight() == requiredWeight)
return parts[i];
}
return;
}
```